# Register a internal class in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

How can you register an internal class from a different assembly, in a unity container?

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IPublicInterface, InternalClassImpl>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Works great if InternalClassImpl is accessible outside it's assembly, but if it's internal, and implements IPublicInterface, the only real alternative seems to be offering a factory that can create them.

But If you have a factory creating the class, How can you continue to use Dependency Injection with Unity to inject it's dependencies?

`Large Application`

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IPublicInterface>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
InternalClassImplFactory.MakeInternalClassImpl()));
```

`Small Library`

```
namespace SmallLibrary
{
    public interface IPublicInterface
    {
    }

    public class InternalClassImplFactory
    {
        public static IPublicInterface MakeInternalClassImpl()
        {
            return new InternalClassImpl();
        }
    }

    internal class InternalClassImpl : IPublicInterface
    {
        public InternalClassImpl()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But what happens if InternalClassImpl needs injected dependencies from Large Application and internal SmallLibrary Classes?

Comment: Do you have the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`?

Comment: @john - its there but that make internal thing visisble outside assembly ...i think its bad practice..if want to expose outside than better to mark as public why to go for that attribut ?

Comment: @Pranay But that's exactly what Ryan is asking to do. He's asking how he can add internal implementations from another assembly into his DI container.

Comment: @john - then it better to make public ...i think

Comment: No I'm asking about best practices, and how to minimize visibility and only show the interface, while still getting a method to construct the class that allows dependencies from LargeApplication

Comment: OK I misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `UnityContainerExtension`.
Create new extension in library where internal class defined. Register your internal class in container.

```
public class Extension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IPublicInterface, InternalClassImpl>();
    }
}


public interface IPublicInterface
{
}

internal class InternalClassImpl : IPublicInterface
{
    public InternalClassImpl()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can expose your implementation via the `Extension`.
So, your implementation stays `internal` but you can use it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddNewExtension<Extension>();
}
```

Comment: Cheers this is similar to what I was imagining, apologies for editing the question slightly, but would this also allow InternalClassImpl to have dependencies on both LargeApplication and SmallLibrary as it grows?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach `InternalClassImpl` can have any dependencies due to its internal nature. So, it's very good way to hide implementation of your contracts

Comment: How would you handle the lifecycle? would that be the responsibility of the extension, or can it also be overridden by the parent?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach you can pass LifeTimeManager via constructor of `Extension` calss and use it. And register like this `container.AddExtension(new Extension(new PerResolvelifeTimeManager()));`

Answer (score -1):

Whilst the accepted answer suited my needs, I think an alternative would be to have the factory method take the container.

```
public class InternalClassImplFactory
    {
        public static IPublicInterface MakeInternalClassImpl(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            return new InternalClassImpl();
        }
    }
```

When registering the factory method, c represents the unity container!

`LargeApplication`

```
container.RegisterType<IPublicInterface>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
InternalClassImplFactory.MakeInternalClassImpl(c)));
```

So you can have the factory create a child container, resolve dependencies or anything you need.

Comment: I think, it's solution for another problem. When you really need a factory. Not in your case